# backbone.js for rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.0, backbone.js-collections

I am using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3

I tried to use gem "rails-backbone", '0.9.10' but it is not working properly as per REST

Are there any other changes required to bo done for rails 3.2.13?

I used scaffold to generate crud but REST api is not working with crud operations

Comment: define 'not working properly?

Comment: I used scaffold to generate crud operations.But the create, edit, delete are not working as per REST (AJAX TYPE)

Comment: you scaffolded in rails but you need to setup backbone (specially urls) so that backbone is aware of your restful endpoints.